# nothing happen in search form

Tags: theme-development

I want to create search form but when I search something nothing happen
and this is the code:
index.php:

```
 <div class="tech-btm">
      <?php get_search_form();?>
 </div>
```

searchform:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/')?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

what is the problem?
Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also put code in index.php to actually display the search results?

https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-search-page/